# Make jar library from source in Intellij Idea 13

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

I have import a directory in Intellij idea 13 with the following file structure:

```
gtransapi/
├── .idea
│   ├── .name
│   ├── artifacts
│   │   └── gtransapi_jar.xml
│   ├── compiler.xml
│   ├── copyright
│   │   └── profiles_settings.xml
│   ├── encodings.xml
│   ├── gtransapi.iml
│   ├── misc.xml
│   ├── modules.xml
│   ├── scopes
│   │   └── scope_settings.xml
│   ├── vcs.xml
│   └── workspace.xml
└── src
    └── com
        └── gtranslate
            ├── Audio.java
            ├── Language.java
            ├── Main.java
            ├── Translator.java
            ├── URLCONSTANTS.java
            ├── parsing
            │   ├── Parse.java
            │   ├── ParseTextDetect.java
            │   └── ParseTextTranslate.java
            ├── text
            │   ├── Text.java
            │   └── TextTranslate.java
            └── utils
                └── WebUtils.java

10 directories, 22 files
```

This is a library for using google's translate service. I want to build it into a jar file for distribution, but can't make it work.

build jar file from module in Intellij Idea 13

file -- project structure -- artifacts -- + -- jar -- from modules with dependencies -- fill "Main" in the main class field.

Then build -- build artifacts. The status bar says build successful, but when I inspect it from intellij, it is almost empty:

[image]
<sub>(source: [p.im9.eu](http://p.im9.eu/host1407012953-093016.jpg))</sub>

Any ideas?

Comment: The image became unavailable. Can you update it / update the "Alt text" with something more relevant?

Answer (score 1):

open your project , go to **file** menu , click on the **project structure** and go to the **artifacts**,click on '**+**' and click on jar and choose From "**Modules to dependencies**" then declare your **Main** class with browse button (**Search By Name Tab**) to added **jar** file then Press **Ok**,
**3 Step Remaining : Rebuilt your project -> generate your Ant build then build Artifacts**
then click on your jar file and Enjoy!
tested with Intellij Idea 13.1.4

Comment: Why does a Jar library need a "main"?

Comment: It's unnecessary to define jar entry point in itself. But as op wants to create jar file with main class (Maybe for simplicity) It must be define.